# Check exist multiple value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from table by checking some conditions:

Table Detail

```
CODE    | PRODUCT |
FWD 4X4 | PROD1   |
```

Table Header

```
CODE    | GROUP |
FWD     | AAA   |
4X4     | AAA   |
FWD     | CCC   |
```

Expected Result

```
CODE    | PRODUCT | GROUP | 
FWD 4X4 | PROD1   | AAA   |
```

Because group AAA have two codes: FWD & 4X4. Group CCC not qualified because only have one code. 
Is it possible to do this by SQL query? I've tried with split string and cross apply not even close though.

Maybe I will use programming language if it's too complex. Since I am not really good with SQL.
Code combination maybe become longer too (3 words or more).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't store data like that (with several codes, space separated). It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Fix your data model!  A place is start is by learning what a junction/association table is:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity.

Comment: thanks for comment @jarlh, it seems hard to change current table condition. Maybe I will find another way.

Comment: What is hard about changing this table structure?

Comment: I talk about existing data on current running application. @iamdave

Comment: So what would your group be if FWD and 4X4 had different groups?

Answer (score 0):

Use String_agg function if your sql server version is 17

```
select a.code,a.prod,a.group from tabledetail a
inner join 
(SELECT [group], STRING_AGG (code, ' ') as c
FROM tableheader     
GROUP BY [group]) b on a.code=b.c
```

for lower version you can use stuff function:

```
select a.code,a.prod,a.group from tabledetail a
    inner join
(SELECT [group],  c= STUFF(
             (SELECT ' ' + code
              FROM tableheader t1
              WHERE t1.id = t2.id
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') from tableheader t2
group by [group])b on a.code=b.c
```

Answer (score 0):

build the schema

```
create table Detail (CODE varchar(300) ,PRODUCT varchar(100) );
insert into Detail values ('FWD 4X4','PROD1');
insert into Detail values ('FWD','PROD2');
insert into Detail values ('FWD 4X4 FM','PROD3');
create table Header (CODE varchar(300) ,[GROUP] varchar(100) );
insert into Header values ('FWD','AAA');
insert into Header values ('4X4','AAA');
insert into Header values ('FWD','CCC');
insert into Header values ('4X4','DDD');
insert into Header values ('FM','DDD');
insert into Header values ('FWD','DDD');
```

solution sql

```
select d.CODE, d.PRODUCT, h.[GROUP]
 from Detail d
 inner join  Header h on CHARINDEX(' ' +h.code+ ' ', ' ' + d.Code + ' ') > 0
 inner join (
             select [Group],count(Code) GroupCodesCount 
             from Header
             Group By [Group]
            ) GroupCodes on GroupCodes.[Group] = h.[GROUP]
 group by d.CODE, d.PRODUCT, h.[GROUP],GroupCodesCount
 having len(d.CODE) - len(replace(d.CODE, ' ', '')) +1 = count(h.code) and count(h.code) = GroupCodesCount
```

output result

```
CODE        PRODUCT GROUP
FWD         PROD2   CCC
FWD 4X4     PROD1   AAA
FWD 4X4 FM  PROD3   DDD
```

I join Detail table with Header when it contains at least one code on the group  `CHARINDEX(' ' +h.code+ ' ', ' ' + d.Code + ' ') > 0` then join it to count codes of each group view after that I group it by product and group then filter result groups to return groups that match exactly count of group codes `having len(d.CODE) - len(replace(d.CODE, ' ', '')) +1 = count(h.code) and count(h.code) = GroupCodesCount`

Hope it helps